# A challenge, moment, the deciding moment

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that captures the idea of someone that's about to embark on a challenging pursuit.

"This was his ____"

I'm trying to capture the idea that the pursuit is longer than a moment but not long as if the individual was going on an epic journey.

Words that have the idea of training, camp, pursuit, challenge, test

. It can even be a metaphor. For example, I might say 'His Achilles heel was alcohol'.

Thanks

Comment: The word *moment* by itself conveys immediacy and importance.

Comment: Hi Jack, moment does capture the importance of the task. However, it conveys an instance in time. I'm looking for a word/s that more enduring.

Comment: "Achilles heel" isn't a single word. Are metaphors exempt?

Comment: ..... 'entry test'

Answer (score 1):

“This was his **Rubicon**”

For example:

> [Science Direct](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-sciences/peasantry)
>
> … *in 1910 Malinowski crossed the English Channel to enrol as a graduate student in ethnology at the London School of Economics (LSE) in the University of London. The crossing **was his Rubicon**, and although not granted British nationality until 1931, he was to spend his most productive years in England*

The usage stems from the significance of Caesar’s crossing of the River Rubicon in 49BC, which marked the start of his progress to becoming emperor of Rome. In general it refers to a recognisable first event in a train of development of significant later events.

Answer (score 0):

**acid test** (n.)

> The acid test of something is an important aspect or result that it
> might have, which allows you to decide whether it is true or
> successful [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/acid-test)

> A conclusive test of the success or value of something.
>
> *Crisis management is the **acid test** of leadership.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/acid_test)

---

> President Ford threw himself into an extensive programme of
> consultation with members of congress on behalf of his new policy, but
> his performance in this **acid test** of presidential leadership was
> unimpressive. [David Mervin; *Ronald Regan*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ronald_Reagan/BHx_BAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=his%20acid%20test%20challenging%20pursuit&pg=PA54&printsec=frontcover) (2014)